# How to run SQL Update query through PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, button, onclick

This problem has been troubling me for the last two weeks. I have looked through almost every question in StackOverflow relating to mine, and none of the answers have helped me. Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost" , "Brian" , "pass123") or die("can't  connect");
mysql_select_db("2015") or die("Can't Select");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, Status FROM Users");  



echo "<hr><br><br><br><center><div class=table-responsive>
<table class='table-bordered table-hover' width=50%>
<tr>
    <td colspan=6 bgcolor=white><center><div><h1><b>Users</b></h1></div>    </center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Username&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Password&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;First Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Last Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Current &nbsp;&nbsp;Status&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div>  </b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Change &nbsp;&nbsp;Status&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   echo "<tr><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<center>".$row['Username']."</b><br><br></td><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<center>".$row['Password']."</center><br></b></td><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<center>".$row['FirstName']."</center></b><br></td><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><center>".$row['LastName']."</center><br><br></b></td><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<center>".$row['Status']."d</center></b><br></td><td>";

if ($row['Status'] == "Enable"){
   echo "<div><a href=\"USERS.php?id=".$row['ID']."\"><button class='btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block' type='Status'><b>Disable</b></button></a></div></tr>";

   if($id != NULL){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `Floral` SET `Status`=\"Disable\" WHERE `ID` = ".$ID."");
   }
}
else if($row['Status'] == "Disable"){
   echo "<div><a href=\"USERS.php?ID=".$row['ID']."\"><button class='btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block' type='Status'><b>Enable</b></button></a></div>    </tr>";
       if($id != NULL){
       $query="UPDATE Floral SET Status='Enabled' WHERE Status='Disabled'";
           $result=mysql_query($query);
       }
    }
        }
?>
```

Basically, I am displaying a table from the database. When the 'Disable' button is clicked for a user that is currently 'Enable', then a MySQL statement should be run, updating that particular row's status to 'Disable". And the same goes in order to 'Enable' a particular row.

Please help! I have been trying to accomplish this for two weeks, and some nights I have stayed up really late trying to get this problem solved. I will be thankful for any help. If there are any edits that I should make about my question, let me know, and I will edit it. I just want to get this fixed.

Comment: Have you tried to `echo $row['Status']` ? Also, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead. Your PHP codes look messy too. Make sure you checked the result of query. Last, it's recommended to use lower-case file names only.

Comment: you don't want the disable action inside the while loop

Comment: (1) you never set `$id`, but check it with `if($id != NULL)`, and (2) in your `if` you are using `$ID` instead of `$id` -> `... WHERE \`ID\` = ".$ID."`, and (3) in your `else if` you don't use a `WHERE `ID`, and (4) you are trying to do the `UPDATE` **after** you display the button, so even if the `UPDATE` was successful then your button would be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are reading from table FLORAL.  You appear to be confused about PHP.  It runs on the server, not the client side.

Your display file should be

```
echo "<hr><br><br><br><center><div class=table-responsive>
<table class='table-bordered table-hover' width=50%>
<tr>
    <td colspan=6 bgcolor=white><center><div><h1><b>Users</b></h1></div></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Username&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Password&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;First Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Last Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Current &nbsp;&nbsp;Status&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div>  </b></th>
    <th><div><h2><b>&nbsp;Change &nbsp;&nbsp;Status&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></div></b></th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   $id = $row['ID'];
   echo "<tr><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<center>".$row['Username'].
        "</b><br><br></td> <td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<center>".$row['Password'].
        "</center><br></b></td><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<center>".
        $row['FirstName']."</center></b><br></td><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><center>".
        $row['LastName']."</center><br><br></b></td><td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<center>".
        $row['Status']."d</center></b><br></td><td>";

if ($row['Status'] == "Enable"){
   echo "<div><a href=\"USERS.php?id=".$id."&status=Disable\"><button class='btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block' type='Status'><b>Disable</b></button></a></div></tr>";
   }
else if($row['Status'] == "Disable"){
   echo "<div><a href=\"USERS.php?ID=".$id."&status=Enable\"><button class='btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block' type='Status'><b>Enable</b></button></a></div>    </tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Then you have the **USERS.PHP** file that does just the update.  I have removed the update statements from the above as they  go in the 2nd file that does just the modification.  You can always run the display file from there after the update has taken place.  I have also added a 2nd param to the href to pass whether the row shoulod be enabled or disabled. when the button is pressed.

**NOTE**

There are better ways to do all this.  When you have this working and get sick of the flicker, read up about **AJAX**.

Comment: Thank you Rohit! I'll try this code out and let you know! I really appreciate the help!